# What is the simplest way to convert convert 5V DC to 100V DC, 0.2 Amps?

Tags: power-supply

What will be the simplest way to convert convert 5V DC to 100V DC, for low power application ~0.2 Amps for a portable electrophoresis power supply?

Comment: Define simplest? Make /buy  = Buy  Then define budget, cost , time , equip. experience  20W 100V is usually a flyback design for low cost but you may want low noise which depends on how low radiated , CM and ripple

Comment: 100V times 0.2A is 20W -- that's 4A from your 5VDC supply, assuming 100% efficiency.  Is that *really* what you want to do?  Do you have mains power available?

Comment: hacktastical the answer you provided was really usefull, thanks

Comment: I'd say "a relay".

Comment: Is your project for medical electrophoresis? If this is the case, "simple" may not be a sufficient specification to avoid LIFE LOSS! Keep in mind that in most coutries there are very strict regulations about electronic medical equipment. Using a non-compliant device on a living person could expose you to legal consequences. Producers of medical equipment have to do lots of paperwork just to have the authorization to perform tests on human beings with their prototypes. Since you didn't specify further details, I stand on the safe side and I assume you could not know what you are doing.

Comment: BTW, if you are thinking about a medical application, 0.2A@100V is more than enough to kill a person if applied to them due to a circuit failure. There have to be several stages of protection circuits to avoid that outcome.

Comment: Hi Lorenzo, I think I will be using the same measures as those in current electrophoresis apparatus